# DHL currency problem

Tags: shipping, error, ce-1.8.1.0, dhl

Shipping from Taiwan to worldwide.

The DHL response XML works on debug log,but Magento always showing : "This shipping method is currently unavailable."

How do I fix that?

---

Here is the debug dump.

```
2014-02-27T06:09:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => Exchange rate TWD (Base Currency) -> USD not found. DHL method Express worldwide skipped
    [1] => Zero shipping charge for 'Express worldwide'
    [__pid] => 53383
)
```

---

My test Origin is

- TAIWAN
- 42751
- TANTZ

Test Destination is

- UNITED STATES OF AMERICA
- 22602
- WINCHESTER

Magento Edition is CE 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your store is looking for an exchange rate that doesn't exist...

To add an exchange rate go to System > Manage Currency > Rates and set up an exchange rate for TWD -> USD

I haven't worked with the DHL module personally, but I hope this helps!